# can't show facebook og:image when share page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I use meta tags on my songs page like...

`<meta property="og:url" content="{{ route(Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName(),$coverSong->cover_slug) }}">
    <meta property="og:type" content="Website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{ $coverSong->cover_name }}">
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{ ($coverSong->youtube_thumb) ? 'https://'.$coverSong->youtube_thumb : asset('assets/images/music.png')}}">
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="{{ ($coverSong->youtube_thumb) ? 'https://'.$coverSong->youtube_thumb : asset('assets/images/music.png')}}">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Listening {{ $coverSong->cover_name }} (Cover song of {{ $originalSong->name }})">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="coversage.com">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">`
but i cant show image on my share popup
[image]

facebook gives error like...
`Object at URL 'http://coversage.com/cover/bewajah-cover/songs' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/kVG-kTPqy1E/mqdefault.jpg' for property 'og:image:secure_url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is too small. Minimum size constraint of 200px by 200px.
Look here

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcoversage.com%2Fcover%2Fbewajah-cover%2Fsongs
```